# Next.js dynamic page not being crawled by SEO

Tags: javascript, next.js, web-crawler, seo, static-site

I have a blog website in Next.Js that has a dynamic page for this route: `article/[slug]`. I'm using this [screaming frog](https://screamingfrog.co.uk/login/) to crawl and index the pages and although initially before setting a custom domain, the articles were getting indexed, now the only page that appears is the homepage:

[image]

I have a **robots.txt** file, a **sitemap** generator component, I've run `npm run build` and deploy on **Vercel**.

Here's **[slug]** component:

```
import AppIcon from "components/AppIcon/AppIcon";
import AppImage from "components/AppImage/AppImage";
import Loading from "components/Loading/Loading";
import PageContainer from "components/PageContainer/PageContainer";
import { ARTICLE_QUERY, graphcms, SLUGLIST } from "pages/api/graphQL/main";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import parser from "react-html-parser";
import styles from "styles/articlepage.module.scss";
import { convertDate } from "utils";
import { getArticleWithGoogleAds } from "utils/googleAds";
import { jost } from "assets/fonts/nextFonts";
import NotFound from "pages/404";
import Head from "components/AppHead/AppHead";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

function Article({ post: articleAPI }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const [article, setArticle] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!articleAPI) {
      return;
    }

    const articleConverted = getArticleWithGoogleAds(articleAPI);

    setArticle(articleConverted);
  }, [articleAPI]);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    } catch (e) {
      return console.log(e);
    }
  }, []);

  if (!article) {
    return (
      <PageContainer>
        <Loading />
      </PageContainer>
    );
  }

  if (!articleAPI && router.isFallback) {
    return <NotFound />;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head
        title={article.title}
        description={article.description}
        image={article.coverPhoto.url}
      />

      <PageContainer>
        <div className={styles.container} style={jost.style}>
          <AppIcon
            icon="arrow-left"
            size={30}
            color="grey"
            className={styles.arrowBack}
            onClick={() => window.history.back()}
          />
          <div>
            {article ? (
              <>
                <div>
                  <h1 className={styles.title}>{article.title}</h1>
                  <div className={styles.subtitle}>
                    <p>{convertDate(article.createdAt)}</p> <span>|</span>{" "}
                    <p>{article.category}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <AppImage
                  className={styles.headerImage}
                  src={article.coverPhoto.url}
                />
                <div className={styles.content}>
                  {parser(article.content.html)}
                </div>
              </>
            ) : (
              <Loading />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </PageContainer>
    </>
  );
}

export default Article;

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { posts } = await graphcms.request(SLUGLIST);

  const paths = posts.map((post) => {
    return { params: { slug: post.slug } };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: false
  };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const slug = params.slug;

  const data = await graphcms.request(ARTICLE_QUERY, { slug });

  const post = data.post;

  return {
    props: { post: post },
    revalidate: 10
  };
}
```

Here's **AppHead** file:

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Head from "next/head";
import React from "react";

function AppHead({
  title,
  description,
  image = "https://media.graphassets.com/m3c024qER0udkPRLgxOI",
  slug
}) {
  return (
    <Head>
      <meta name="description" content={description} key="desc" />
      <meta property="og:title" content={title} />
      <meta property="og:description" content={description} />
      <meta property="og:image" content={image} />
      <meta name="robots" content="/robots.txt" />
      {slug && (
        <>
          <meta
            property="og:url"
            content={`https://curiositygem.com/article/${slug}`}
          />
          <link
            rel="canonical"
            href={`https://curiositygem.com/article/${slug}`}
          />
        </>
      )}
      <meta property="og:site_name" content="curiositygem.com" />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content={description} />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content={title} />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <title>{title}</title>
    </Head>
  );
}

AppHead.propTypes = {
  description: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  image: PropTypes.string,
  slug: PropTypes.string
};

export default AppHead;
```

Here's **_app** file:

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import ArticlesProvider from "context/articles-context";
import "styles/global.scss";
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ArticlesProvider>
      <Layout>
        <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Layout>
    </ArticlesProvider>
  );
}
```

Here's the sitemap file:

```
import { graphcms, SLUGLIST } from "./api/graphQL/main";

function generateSiteMap(posts) {
  return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
     ${posts
       .map(
         ({ slug }) => `
       <url>
           <loc>${`https://curiositygem.com/article/${slug}`}</loc>
           <lastmod>${new Date().toISOString()}</lastmod>
           <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
           <priority>1.0</priority>
       </url>`
       )
       .join("")}
   </urlset>
 `;
}

function SiteMap() {
  return null;
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ res }) {
  // We make an API call to gather the URLs for our site
  const data = await graphcms.request(SLUGLIST);
  const posts = data["posts"];

  // We generate the XML sitemap with the posts data
  const sitemap = generateSiteMap(posts);

  res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "s-maxage=30, stale-while-revalidate");
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  // we send the XML to the browser
  res.write(sitemap);
  res.end();

  return {
    props: {}
  };
}

export default SiteMap;
```

Here's the build response, with the articles:

[image]

I've no idea what to do next :/

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution!

This was happening because of the way I was getting the articles on the homepage. When the web crawler hits the homepage, he needs to execute Javascript from my custom hook `useArticles` to get the posts from context, and since web crawlers don't run javascript, he got stuck on **loading**, not reaching the links of the posts and therefore not rendering each post route.

I hope this helps you in the future :)